# relation between eigen values and principal component

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, pca

what is the relation between principal components and eigen values (in PCA) ?
suppose i have calculated PCA for two regions in an image separately, from the eigen values of these two regions what we can interpret ?

Comment: As @Roger has said below, there is no way to use the eigenvalues to determine how similar two images are. In fact that is not the way to use PCA to compare images. Instead, the eigenvectors found by PCA are used to describe the images is a new coordinate system where you can then compared similarities and differences between images by projecting your images onto this coordinate space.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of the eigenvalues indicates the degree of variance in the data along the corresponding eigenvector. If you are using PCA for dimensionality reduction, you choose which eigenvectors to retain based on the eigenvalues.

If you have performed PCA on two independent regions, there is not necessarily *any* correlation between the resulting eigen decompositions. All it may be useful for is to identify some shape characteristics, for example by allowing you to compare ratios of the major vs minor principal axes.

What is your real question?

Comment: i got a program in which wrongly detected license plates regions in a frame are removed based on eigen values obtained from that regions..

Comment: @Deepak it seems like your question is much too general then. Why not edit it to show some example images, some source code, the expected result and the actual result. Then you can get better feedback (if this is an implementation issue or a design issue for example).